# Xcode: how to build for older Intel processors (i5, Core 2 Duo) on i7

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, llvm-clang

My application is crashing when built on a new Apple laptop and then launched on a much older Apple laptop.

The application is built using Xcode 6.4, on OSX 10.9 and 10.10, when using llvm 6.1 and C++11. The SDK is 10.10, the target OSX is 10.7. Optimizations are off.

The crash is very very early on when the C runtime is loading my application binary and initializing the modules.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.MyCompany.MyApplication     0x000000010cd10e7a _GLOBAL__I_a + 10
1   dyld                            0x00007fff61fd3ceb ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 265
2   dyld                            0x00007fff61fd3e78 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
3   dyld                            0x00007fff61fd0871 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int,
```

This is before any of my application code. The crash does not occur on the build machine (i7 CPU). Crashes occur on i5 and Core 2 Duo machines. I suspect that an extended (CPU specific) instruction is creating the crash on load.

When I use the same Xcode, same llvm, etc to build the application on the Core 2 Duo machine there is no crash.

I am also using homebrew: libmtp, libusb, libusb-compat, cryptopp, curl (with c-ares, openssl, nghttp2), boost.  I have specified C++11 where necessary, and have specified --build-bottle. I am statically linking to these libraries.

I have tried to use otool -tV on all libraries, the final binary, etc to find SSE instructions.

I have tried to set the Xcode LLVM build setting "Enable Additional Vector Extensions" to "platform" and "SSE3" to no avail.  This is probably because homebrew isn't passing the --universal flag from curl to the building of openssl and it's cryptlib.

I have taken static libraries libcurl.a (CURL), libssl.a (OpenSSL), libcrypto.a (OpenSSL), libz.a (zlib) from the older machine and added them to my repository. Using Xcode to link them into my application solves the problem.

Are there other tools I can should use to narrow down the offending instruction?
Are there other explanations for the crash?

Addendum:
In addition to building the libraries on an older machine, I have also created a proof of concept, minimal, instant crash program that reports a slightly different crash location, but demonstrates the issue:

On an i7 (new Apple computer with new Intel CPU), use homebrew to install:
    brew install curl --with-c-ares --with-openssl

Then copy this source into file sse.cpp:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it:

```
clang++ sse.cpp -c -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include
clang++ -o a.out sse.o /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a /usr/local/opt/zlib/lib/libz.a /usr/local/opt/curl/lib/libcurl.a /usr/local/opt/c-ares/lib/libcares.a -stdlib=libc++ -framework LDAP
```

Now move to an older Apple computer with older Intel CPU, and crash it:

```
./a.out
```

Crash Report (compressed):

```
Process:               a.out [569]
...
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [448]
Responsible:           Terminal [339]
...
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
...
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   a.out                           0x000000010dbdce3f ENGINE_new + 36
1   a.out                           0x000000010dbe05e3 ENGINE_load_dynamic + 11
2   a.out                           0x000000010dbdf04a ENGINE_load_builtin_engines + 24
3   a.out                           0x000000010dc76b36 Curl_ossl_init + 14
4   a.out                           0x000000010dc5c2a5 curl_global_init + 114
5   a.out                           0x000000010db51d95 main + 37
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff88b735c9 start + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to involve using:

```
export HOMEBREW_BUILD_BOTTLE=1
export HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_ARCH=core2
```

When building the homebrew libraries. Using [Intel XED](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/xed-x86-encoder-decoder-software-library) I was able to check the emitted machine code for unsupported instructions:

```
xed_cmd="/usr/local/bin/xed"
ar -x libcurl.a
parts=(*.o)
for j in "${parts[@]}"; do
    chipcheck=$(${xed_cmd} -i ${j} -chip-check ${chipToCheck})
    chiperrors=$(echo "${chipcheck}" | grep "# Total Chip Check Errors")

    if [[ "$chiperrors" != "# Total Chip Check Errors: 0" ]] ; then
        echo ERROR ${libname} ${j} $chiperrors
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your code work when you disable compiler optimizations?  If not, how about trying an older version of Xcode?  It could just be a compiler bug, though I'd hope not!  If you can find a working compiler or set of compiler options to check against, you could use LLVM's [bugpoint](http://llvm.org/docs/Bugpoint.html) tool to isolate which file is being miscompiled.

Comment: Turning optimizations off doesn't help, even debug builds crash. The problem started with an older version of the compiler, but now both the Core 2 Duo machine and the i7 are using the same Xcode, same llvm.

Comment: You can download older Xcode versions from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ — looks like you’ll have to go back further then.

Comment: See latest findings above.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you can target a miscompilation in cryptopp instead.  Should have mentioned if it is a `dyld` issue you may be able to use the `DYLD_` environment variables (see the `dyld` man page) to figure out what is happening during runtime loading. `DYLD_PRINT_INITIALIZERS` in particular sounds applicable.

Comment: Everything is statically linked. Except for system frameworks.